# QGIS 3.x Problem Import PDF on Raster-Layer

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, import, pdf

While dropping georeferenced PDF into canvas, image-data ist lost.
Even in older Projects, the image-data is not shown any longer.
Uninstall and reinstall QGIS does not help.
Import PDF to rasterlayer does not work at all.
Import PDF to Vectorlayer exctracts only lines and Text.

Comment: There are a lot of details missing here. Which QGIS version are you working with? Did you try other versions? Did you try other PDFs? Does this affect all PDF, or only those created after an update? Did you update QGIS recently?

Comment: Tried on 3.16.8- Hannover and Updat 3.16.9

Comment: It happens on all PDFs after Popup: "projecttransformation not available" Install Grid Https://cdn.proj.ord/de_adv_BETA2007.tif

Comment: After that I triede everything to reproject, but pixeldata are not shown any longer. So I deleted Qgis fully, even da_adv_BETA2007.tif an reinstalled. But the problem still exists.